# Django no access to certain methods AbstractUser using UserManager

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am new to Django I am trying to get access to `form.save()` using `form = self.form_class(request.POST)` but I have been having to use methods like `self.get_form_class()` to access `form.is_valid()` and `form.save()` but cannot get method `set_password()` from `user = form.save(commit=False)` I am not sure what the problem is. Why cant I access `user.set_password()`? Even when I try to create a `BaseUserManager` `self.model()` does not give me a definition for `user.set_password()` or `user.save()` why is this?

```
# views.py
class RegistrationView(CreateView):

    template_name = "AskQuestions/customuser_form.html"
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    model = CustomUser
    success_url = "questions/login"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form_class()
        form = form(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.get_form_class()
        form = form(request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid()):
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            # user.set_password() no definition
            user.set_password()

            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Your account has been successfully created.")
            return redirect("AskQuestions:login")
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

# models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name", "phone_number"]

# forms.py
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label="Confirm password:", max_length=200, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "username", "phone_number", "password",]

        labels = {
            "first_name": "Name:",
            "last_name": "Last name:",
            "username": "Username",
            "phone_number": "Phone number:",
            "password": "Password",
            "confirm_password": "Confirm password:",
        }

        widgets = {
            "first_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "last_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "username": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "phone_number": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "password": forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data

        first_name = data["first_name"]
        last_name = data["last_name"]
        username = data["username"]
        password = data["password"]
        confirm_password = data["confirm_password"]
        
        if not first_name:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must supply a name.")
        if not last_name:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must supply a last name.")
        if not username:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must supply a username.")
        else:
            username_exists = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
            if (username_exists):
                self.add_error("username", "This username has already been taken.")

        if not password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must supply a password.")
        if not confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must supply a password to compare against.")
        if not password == confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")
        return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could create `RegistrationForm` inherited from `UserCreationForm`

```
# forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "username", "phone_number",)
```

regarding `clean` method - you dont have to check if user send some certain field, just in your CustomUser model you have to add those fields without `null=True`, `blank=True`. as an example:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150)
```

and now i could delete checks for first_name in your Registration form clean-method. As result of this refactoring - clean-method should be deleted.
Dont worry about `confirm_password` field, it exists in UserCreationForm but called as `password2`, original password called as `password1`. and checks for password in this form also exists

2. Answer for your question with the `set_password` from the previous point we got a form inherited from `UserCreationForm` which have this `set_password` logic already written in save method. You just need to call `form.save()`
   so your post-method in view:

```py
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.get_form_class()
        form = form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Your account has been successfully created.")
            return redirect("AskQuestions:login")
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```